# Parametro string en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de pasar un parametro con un valor string a través de un boton con el evento onclick, pero me muestra erro, sin embargo, le paso un numero como parametro y me lo toma

```
echo "<td>";
echo "<button  name='nombre' type='submit' class='btn btn-success' onclick='accion( 'Rafael');'> AUTORIZAR</button>";
echo "</td>";

function accion(a){
 alert(a);
 <?php echo "Entrar";
$stid =  oci_parse($conn, "DELETE FROM TAB_AUTO 
where autofue='IN'
and autodoc='1017951'
and autolin= 1"); 
oci_execute($stid); ?>
}
```

Este es el error que me muestra en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu problema son las comillas. Al hacer + `onclick='accion( 'Rafael');'` esta rompiendo las comillas del atributo. Prueba a hacer `onclick='accion( "Rafael");'`

Comment: Acabo de cambiarlo como dices pero me marca ahora el siguiente error:
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Rafael' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\index1.php on line 188

Comment: Perdon, se me olvidarón los caracteres de escape. `onclick='accion( \"Rafael\");'`

Comment: Tambien lo estoy pasando a través de una variable pero me marca este error:
`$prueba = "Rafael";

echo "<td>";
echo "<button  name='nombre' type='submit' class='btn btn-success' onclick='accion( {$prueba});'> AUTORIZAR</button>";
echo "</td>";`

error explorador: index1.php:57 Uncaught ReferenceError: Rafael is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Eso es porque interpreta el valor de la variable. Si lo quieres con variable creo que tiene que ser `onclick='accion( \'{$prueba}\');'`

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvio mucho

Comment: De nada. Un placer.

Comment: Pónganlo como respuesta y acéptenlo para que otros sepan cómo se resolvió

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo de forma mas sencilla con las funciones [EOF](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) y [addslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.addslashes.php):

```
$str = <<<EOF
<td>
<button  name='nombre' type='submit' class='btn btn-success' onclick='accion( 'Rafael');'> AUTORIZAR</button>
</td>
EOF;
// agrgamos slashes para escapar los caracteres y luego imprimimos
echo addslashes( $str );


function accion(a){
 alert(a);
 <?php echo "Entrar";
$stid =  oci_parse($conn, "DELETE FROM TAB_AUTO 
where autofue='IN'
and autodoc='1017951'
and autolin= 1"); 
oci_execute($stid); ?>
}
```